# ZF2 - set selected value on Select Element

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've a problem with dropdown list with Zend Framework 2 & Doctrine.
I would put the "selected" attribute on my dropdown list but all options pass to selected

My code :

**Controller :**

```php
public function editAction()
{
    // get error message during addAction
    $this->layout()->setVariable("messageError", $this->flashMessenger()->getErrorMessages());

    $auth = $this->getAuthService();
    if ($auth->hasIdentity()){
        $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
        // Get id of StaticContent
        $id = (int)$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
        if (!$id) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Aucun plan choisi !");
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/plans');
        }
        $plan = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Admin\Entity\Plan")->find((int)$id);
        $form = $builder->createForm($plan);
        // Find options for Localite list (<select>)
        $localites = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Admin\Entity\Localite")->getArrayOfAll();
        $form->get('localiteid')->setValueOptions($localites);
        $form->get('localiteid')->setValue("{$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId()}");

        // Find options for TypePlan list (<select>)
        $typesPlan = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Admin\Entity\TypePlan")->getArrayOfAll();
        $form->get('typeid')->setValueOptions($typesPlan);
        $form->get('typeid')->setValue("{$plan->getTypeid()->getId()}");
        // Options for Statut list (<select>)
        $form->get('statut')->setValueOptions(array('projet'=>'Projet', 'valide'=>'Validé'));
        $form->get('statut')->setValue($plan->getStatut());
        $form->setBindOnValidate(false);
        $form->bind($plan);
        $form->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Modifier',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => "btn btn-primary"
            ),  
        ));
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            [...]

            }
}
```

With

```php
$localites = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Admin\Entity\Localite")->getArrayOfAll();
    $form->get('localiteid')->setValueOptions($localites);
```

i populate my dropdown correctly, normally with

```php
$form->get('localiteid')->setValue("{$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId()}");
```

just set "selected" on option defined by :

```php
$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId()
```

So why all options are selected in my dropdown ?!

**Information : It's the same for typeId but no Statut**

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not working because of the curly braces. According to the [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) documentation

> Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.

This is also unnecessary when using setValue. ZF2 will convert it to a string when formatting it in the view.

When you create the arrays to pass to setValueOptions() you should make it an associative array of arrays with the following values:

```
$form->get('select')->setValueOptions(array(
  'field' => array(
      'value' => 'value_of_the_option',
      'label' => 'what is displayed',
      'selected' => true,
  ),
));
```

Which ever of the fields has the selected option set to true will be the default selection in the form element.

Comment: Thx ! I test it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i don't know if getArrayOfAll() such function exists, i assume that you are correctly passing array to FORM,

I think you should be doing something like this to set value.

```
 $form->get('localiteid')->setValue($plan->getLocaliteid()->getId());
```

But Since you are populating DROP down i guess this approach will not work best with Drop Down. You need to do something like this

```
   $form->get('localiteid')->setAttributes(array('value'=>$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId(),'selected'=>true));
```

Comment: getArrayOfAll() is a Repository method. It's a custom find() in my Localite RepositoryClass. I will use the @Adrian 's method

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bug ?!

```php
$plan = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Admin\Entity\Plan")->find((int)$id);
$idLocalite = 18;//(int)$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId();
$idTypePlan = 2;//(int)$plan->getTypeid()->getId();
```

When i'm using `$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId();` or `$plan->getTypeid()->getId()` to pass parameter into Repository method `getArrayOfAll($idLocalite)`

LocaliteRepository.php :

```php
class LocaliteRepository extends EntityRepository {

  public function getArrayOfAll($currentLocaliteId) {
    $result = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT l.nom, l.localiteid FROM Admin\Entity\Localite l ORDER BY l.nom")->getArrayResult();
    $localite = array();
    foreach($result as $loc) {
        if ($currentLocaliteId == $loc['localiteid']) {
            $localite[$loc['localiteid']] = array(
                    'value' => $loc['localiteid'],
                    'label' => $loc['nom'],
                    'selected' => true,
            );
        } else {
            $localite[$loc['localiteid']] = array(
                    'value' => $loc['localiteid'],
                    'label' => $loc['nom'],
                    'selected' => false
            );
            //$localite[$loc['localiteid']] = $loc['nom'];
        }
    }

    return $localite;
  }
```

}

So, if i'm using `$idLocalite = 18` instead of `$idLocalite = (int)$plan->getLocaliteid()->getId()` only wanted option are selected. Why ?!

Comment: Sorry, not quite understanding the question. It only works when you pass in 18? or it selects the wrong things when you pass in 18? I suggest you perhaps dump $localite before passing it to the Select element and see it's structure. If the issue is that it only works correctly when you pass in 18 then there's something wrong with the query that gets $plan.